# How to change the body background for every id page?

Tags: html, css, background-color

I want to change the body background into different color when I click a page. My HTML code is only one page so the pages are classified into `<div>`s. I don't want to change the background of the id. I only want to change the color of the Body.

I tried:

```
body #home {background-color:#099;}
```

But it only changes within the dimensions of the **#home div** and not the body background

I tried:

```
body#home {background-color:#099;}
```

but nothing happens.

Comment: what exactly are you expecting?

Comment: whats wrong with `body {background-color:#099;}` as it changes body color  ?

Comment: I'm with @JJPA - I don't see what the problem is.

Comment: It sounds like you mean you want to change the body color on pages that contain a `#home` div, but not on pages that don't contain a `#home` div? However, that doesn't fit with you having only one HTML page.

Comment: @MrLister — It sounds like an over-Ajaxed situation. So one real page, with multiple simulated pages via DOM manipulation.

Comment: @Quentin Ah... That's possible. So the solution is, use JS to check if a div with `#home` is pulled in and change the css accordingly.

Comment: @MrLister — Giving the body an id (or class) would be simpler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function changeBackgroundColor(Bodycolor) {
            alert(Bodycolor);
            document.body.style.background = Bodycolor;
        }
    </script>
```

HTML

```
 <div>
        <a onclick="changeBackgroundColor('red');">Home</a> <a onclick="changeBackgroundColor('black');">
            About</a>
    </div>
```

Comment: Hi this code was the one that worked thank you very much! however before it changes the background color, a pop up box opens stating the color then you have to click ok in order for the color to change. Any chance i could get rid of this?

Comment: Nevermind I already fixed it. I just deleted the alert(Bodycolor); Thank you again! :))

Answer (score 2):

There is no way, in CSS, to select an element based on what its descendants are.

Give the body element an id.